# about the Apache Hive Map side Join

Tags: apache, hadoop, dictionary, hive, solid-state-drive

I know that hive map side join uses memory.
Can I use an SSD instead of a memory?
I want to do a mapside join by putting the dimension table on the SSD.
Is it possible?

Comment: you can use `Distributed cahce` (HDFS)

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: what is the execution engine are you using?

Comment: I have not decided yet. but I plan to use tez. Do you recommend another engine?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question by explaining you Hadoop distributed cache:

DistributedCache is a facility provided by the Map-Reduce framework to cache files (***in your case it is hive table which you want to join***) needed by applications.

The DistributedCache assumes that the files specified via urls are already present on the FileSystem (***this is your SSD or HDD***) at the path specified by the url and are accessible by every machine in the cluster.

> So ironically it is the hadoop frame work who decides whether to put the map
>   file in memory(RAM / YARN) or in SSD/HDD depending on the map file
>   size.

Although By default, the maximum size of a table to be used in a map join (as the small table) is 1,000,000,000 bytes (about 1 GB), you can increase this manually also by hive set properties example:

set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask=true;

set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size=2000000000;

The framework will copy the necessary files on to the slave node before any tasks for the job are executed on that node. Its efficiency stems from the fact that the files are only copied once per job and the ability to cache archives which are un-archived on the slaves.

you can find more about distributed cache on this links:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html

Comment: Is that possible?
Please explain intuitively :(